# Azure DevOps Build PIpeline for Winforms Application

Tags: .net, winforms, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a WinForms application. I have created a build pipeline for the same but unable to get anything in Artifacts.

Actually I need the build of the project in the Zipped folder. Any reference for the same will be appreciated.

Following is the Yaml file for the pipeline.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  ScmBuildProject: 'DemoAppForAzurePipeLine'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: $(ScmBuildName)'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(ScmBuildName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your build output is here `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/YourProject/bin/release/'` you can use [archive task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops)

```yaml
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/YourProject/bin/release/'
    #includeRootFolder: true 
    #archiveType: 'zip' # Options: zip, 7z, tar, wim
    #tarCompression: 'gz' # Optional. Options: gz, bz2, xz, none
    #archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip' 
    #replaceExistingArchive: true 
    #verbose: # Optional
    #quiet: # Optional
```

and it puts it then in archiveFile `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'`

Put this step before `PublishBuildArtifacts` and it should be fine. Please double check your output path for your binaries (I mean this `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/YourProject/bin/release/`)

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof. I am able to get the desired result.